# Streaming Netflix in an Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, netflix, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying to make an Android app that will play Netflix in a WebView so that I can mimic the functionality of a Chrome extension. Apparently Netflix doesn't allow streaming on mobile browsers which poses a bit of a problem. When I change the user agent to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`, Netflix shows this error:

> This title is not available to watch instantly. Please try another title. - 1044
> Error Code M7121-1331

I have heard that you can watch Netflix on Safari on an iPad because the user agent is identical to the user agent of a desktop Mac. So I tried changing the user agent to `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_5_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.5 Safari/605.1.15`. Netflix redirects to an article that says that the browser is out of date. I assume that this is because it is expecting a Safari browser with FairPlay DRM support or something. Even if this approach will not work using an Android WebView, could it work on an iOS app using a SFSafariViewController or something?

If changing the user agent is not sufficient, is there a way to use JavaScript to allow streaming? I know that there are browser extensions that use JavaScript to allow 1080p streaming. Could something similar be done to allow streaming in a WebView?

I'm not too optimistic about this working, but I'm hoping that someone with more knowledge than me can tell me whether or not it's possible.